# Performance of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, entity-framework

I have a function, which use EF, but it works too slow...
Do you know any ways, how to improve performance of this function?

```
public static void SaveCombiners()
    {
        using (var db = new IP_dbEntities())
        {
            db.COMBINERs.RemoveRange(db.COMBINERs);
            foreach (var type1 in EventTypesList)
            {
                foreach (var type2 in EventTypesList)
                {
                    db.COMBINERs.Add(new COMBINER()
                    {
                        EVENTS_TYPE = db.EVENTS_TYPE.Single(type => type.event_type == type1),
                        EVENTS_TYPE1 = db.EVENTS_TYPE.Single(type => type.event_type == type2),
                        combine_status = _eventTypesCombinerCollection[type1][type2].Value == true ? "+" : "-"
                    });
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Write it in pure SQL and use `db.Database.ExecuteSqlQuery(sql, params).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Why you write 2 "Foreach" for 1 List?

Comment: Yeah, +1, so what you may find better is to do one set of reads, then do your writes... rather than reading everytime you do a write!!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There are a lot of possible ways to make your code faster, but this is shooting in the dark as you provide zero relevant information. Maybe it is slow because you do not know how to properly define the indices in the database? Why you call Single instead of First... if you know only one is there ,the later is faster (can stop after finding an item).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always use **AddRange** over Add. The Add method will try to DetectChanges every time the add method is invoked while AddRange only once.

```
public static void SaveCombiners()
{
    using (var db = new IP_dbEntities())
    {
        db.COMBINERs.RemoveRange(db.COMBINERs);

        List<COMBINER> list = new List<COMBINER>();

        foreach (var type1 in EventTypesList)
        {
            foreach (var type2 in EventTypesList)
            {
                list.Add(new COMBINER()
                {
                    EVENTS_TYPE = db.EVENTS_TYPE.Single(type => type.event_type == type1),
                    EVENTS_TYPE1 = db.EVENTS_TYPE.Single(type => type.event_type == type2),
                    combine_status = _eventTypesCombinerCollection[type1][type2].Value == true ? "+" : "-"
                });
            }
        }

        db.COMBINERs.AddRange(list);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

That being said, you face another performance issue.

A database round trip is required for every record to delete or to add. So, if you delete 10,000 records and add 5,000 records, 15,000 database round trips will be required which is VERY slow.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library allows you to perform Bulk Operations within Entity Framework. You simply have to change "SaveChanges" by "**BulkSaveChanges**" to dramatically improve performance.

```
public static void SaveCombiners()
{
    using (var db = new IP_dbEntities())
    {
        db.COMBINERs.RemoveRange(db.COMBINERs);
        // ... code..
        db.COMBINERs.AddRange(list);

        db.BulkSaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**RemoveRange** and **AddRange** are too slow, try **ExecuteSqlCommand**

```
MyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from MyTable");
```

Comment: It would be better to use "TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]" command here if all rows need to be deleted

Comment: @AndrewSilver - maybe, but maybe not. Truncate doesn't fire triggers so should be reserved for DDL not DML.

Comment: Its OK, that i use foreach twice, becauce there are the same rows and columns name in my 2 dimentional dictionary